# PostGIS 2.0 st_geomfromgml using LineString fails with invalid GML representation

Tags: geometry, postgis-2.0, gml, linestring, 2d

I am attempting to insert a geometry into a table using the `st_geomfromgml` function.

The GML is being sourced from a Geoserver WFS request.

The function call looks like this

`st_geomfromgml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><gml:LineString xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" srsDimension="2">
 <gml:posList>146.48296 -18.6222 146.48296 -18.6222</gml:posList>
</gml:LineString>');`

This worked on PostGIS version `POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.1-CAPI-1.7.1" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS`

but fails on `POSTGIS="2.0.0 r9605" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN"`

However I can make it work if I specify three dimensions like so;

`select st_geomfromgml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><gml:LineString xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" srsDimension="3">
 <gml:posList>146.48296 -18.6222 0 146.48296 -18.6222 0</gml:posList>
</gml:LineString>');`

Is there a way to keep the geometry in two dimensions and insert it?

Comment: On closer inspection I note that the points in the `LineString` are the same, this appears to be the cause of my problem.